# Python Repeated Actions

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, repeat

I have a list that contains strings

```
animalList=['ASLAN', 'KAPLAN', 'KOPEK', 'KEDI']
descLion = ( 'it is called lion....')
descTiger = (' it is called tiger....')
```

I ask user to enter one of them and check for typos

```
questOne = input("Enter the name of the animal: ")
questOne = questOne.upper()
while questOne not in animalList: 
    questOne = input("Whatch out for typos Try again: ")
    questOne = questOne.upper()
else:
    print(questOne + ' IT IS')
```

What I couldn't figure out is that I want my code to keep ask for a name of the animal, check for typos and print the related description and repeat this action. I have tried something like that;

```
while questOne == animalList[0]:
    print (descLion)
    questOne = input("Enter the name of the animal: ")
    questOne = questOne .upper()

while questOne == animalList[1]:
    print (descTiger)
    questOne = input("Enter the name of the animal: ")
    questOne = questOne.upper()
```

This code kind of works only if the user inputs are in the order of the list. I would like user to be able to enter the input randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use "while True". Example:

```
while True:
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    print("Hi, {}!".format(name))
    print("What about now?")
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy. Thanks a lot!